# Removing items from a userform combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a couple of comboboxes which all have the same values - "", 1-12.  I'm trying to get it so that when a user selects an item, all of the other items disappear.  When a new item is selected, it repopulates the last item.

This is what I have that far.

```
Private Old182 As String
Private Sub ComboBox182_Change()
Dim i
Dim y
If ComboBox182 <> Old182 Then
    For i = 182 To 193
        If i <> 182 Then
            If ComboBox182 <> Old182 Then
                If ComboBox182 <> "" Then
                    Controls("ComboBox" & i).RemoveItem ComboBox182.Value
                    If ComboBox182 <> "" Then
                        If Old182 <> "" Then
                            Controls("ComboBox" & i).AddItem Old182
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
Old182 = ComboBox182.Value
End Sub
```

My first run through, it will remove the first item.  Let's say for example I click 1.  It will remove (1).  If I click 2 it will remove (3).  I believe it does this because it is removing it by index value.  1 => "", (1).  Thus the array is "", 2, 3, etc.  2 => (3).  I'm sorry if that was poorly demoed.  Anyways, how can I get it so that it will remove the value from the array, and reset the array, or how can I remove a value from the array where it matches the value and not the index equaling the index?

***Combobox is being populated via a range on my excel sheet***

Comment: What I can't see is the `.Clear method` which you should possibly use before adding new element. And you have all what you need- just rethink your logic.

Comment: I'm trying to figure a way to properly include your suggestion.  When I add that after the removeitem line it clears out the rest of my boxes as is expected, however, I only want to clear the one item.

Comment: you can't clear one item. You need to clear them all and add new set of correct items again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for my question is as follows:

```
Dim i
Dim y
Dim z As String
z = ""
If ComboBox182 <> Old182 Then
    For i = 182 To 193
        If i <> 182 Then
            If ComboBox182 <> Old182 Then
                If Old182 <> "" Then
                    Controls("ComboBox" & i).AddItem Old182, Old182
                    Controls("ComboBox" & i).RemoveItem (Old182 + 1)
                End If
                Controls("ComboBox" & i).RemoveItem ComboBox182.ListIndex
                Controls("ComboBox" & i).AddItem z, ComboBox182.ListIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
    Old182 = ComboBox182.Value
```

This applies to each combobox with numbers increasing accordingly.  This solution works best in this scenario considering that the values are numeric to begin with and are in order.